# style.css gets included before bootstrap

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, w3-total-cache

i'm trying to overwrite bootstrap with my style.css (placed by default in my wordpress theme folder). so this is the code i have in my functions.php to enqueue the bootstrap cdn and my css:

```
function bootstrap() { 
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap-css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css' ); 
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js',  array('jquery') );

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap');

function maincss() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'maincss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'maincss');
```

and this is what my head looks like in my google's inspector:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="maincss-css" href="http://bootstraptest.co.nf/wp-content/themes/HipsterTheme/style.css?ver=1.0.0" type="text/css" media="screen">

<link rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css-css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css?ver=4.2.3" type="text/css" media="all">
```

i'm pretty new with wordpress so be nice to me :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation [wp_enqueue_style](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), you should declare the dependency of **maincss** using the **$deps** parameter , like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'maincss', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css',array('bootstrap-css') );
```

Comment: thank you it's working now! but i found another problem somewhere else :P

Comment: Can you mark my answer as accepted if it solve your problem? 
Thanks. :)
PS: what problem do you have now?

Comment: i'm using a plugin called w3 total cache, that has a minifier option, but for some reason my css gets minified before bootstrap-css so it get's override again .